# AdMob - handle initialization failures on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'm wondering which is the right way to handle the cases where admob initialization fails.

I'm specifically referring to the cases where we call:

```
MobileAds.Initialize(HandleInitCompleteAction);
```

​And in the handler we obtain "NotReady".

```
private void HandleInitCompleteAction(InitializationStatus initstatus)
    {
        foreach (AdapterStatus s in initstatus.getAdapterStatusMap().Values)
        {
             if (s.InitializationState == AdapterState.NotReady)
            {  // WHAT SHOULD WE DO HERE??? any best practise to try again?
```

Should we retry to initialize the system? Are there any example of code to handle this situation?

In general it should be nice to have a message from Admob that tells us why the initialization is failing :/